# How do I find the geodesic distance between SPD matrices?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I tried using the geom stat package from the following: https://github.com/geomstats/geomstats/blob/master/geomstats/geometry/spd_matrices.py
Ihave the following error so I do need some help: signature = (space.dim, 0)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dim'

```
def svd(A):
    U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=True)
    return U, S, VT

def eigenvalue_decomposition(U):
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(U)
    return eigenvalues, eigenvectors

# Specify matrices X and Y
X = np.array([[1, 3, 4], [1.2, 2.1, 5]])
X2 = np.dot(X,X.T)
XU,XS,XVT = svd(X2)
X_norm=np.sqrt(XS.sum())
X2 = X2/X_norm
X2_symmetric =  0.5 * (X2 + X2.T) 
X2_eigenvalues, X2_eigenvectors = eigenvalue_decomposition(X2_symmetric)
print('Direct eigenvalues of 1/2 (X2 + X2.T):\n', X2_eigenvalues)
print('Direct eigenvectors of 1/2 (X2 + X2.T):\n', X2_eigenvectors)


Y = np.array([[3, 1, 2], [4.1, 3.7, 7.7]])
Y2 = np.dot(Y,Y.T)
YU,YS,YVT = svd(Y2)
Y_norm=np.sqrt(YS.sum())
Y2 = Y2/Y_norm
Y2_symmetric =  0.5 * (Y2 + Y2.T) 
Y2_eigenvalues, Y2_eigenvectors = eigenvalue_decomposition(Y2_symmetric)
print('Direct eigenvalues of 1/2 (Y2 + Y2.T):\n', Y2_eigenvalues)
print('Direct eigenvectors of 1/2 (Y2 + Y2.T):\n', Y2_eigenvectors)


print('X2_symmetric is', X2_symmetric)
print('Y2_symmetric is', Y2_symmetric)
# Example usage
n = 3  # Specify the dimension of the SPD matrices

spd_metric = SPDLogEuclideanMetric(n)

# Compute the Log-Euclidean geodesic distance between X and Y
geodesic_distance = spd_metric.dist(X2_symmetric, Y2_symmetric)

print("Log-Euclidean geodesic distance between X and Y:", geodesic_distance)
```